# Python change "globalish" variable inside a function

Tags: python, variables, global

The following code

```
def myfunc():
  x = ""
  print("Python is " + x)
  def hi():
    global x
    x = "OMG"
  hi()
  print("Python is " + x)
    
myfunc()
```

just prints "Python is" twice.
I was expecting that the second print-statement prints "Python is OMG".

Does some one has an idea how to accomplish that?
I could just declare x as a global variable, but I would like avoid it, because a constraint of my programming task is to only change code inside the myfunc-Function.

Comment: `x` is assigned inside `myfunc()`, so it _isn't_ global.  The x inside `hi()` is a completely different variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Globalish" is spelled [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=nonlocal#grammar-token-python-grammar-nonlocal_stmt) :)

The `x` you want to modify inside `hi` is not a global variable, but a local variable in the enclosing scope, so you use the `nonlocal` keyword to specify the variable named `x` in the closest enclosing scope with such a variable.

```
def hi():
    nonlocal x
    x = "OMG"
```